# Save a comma separated string in double quotes in java hashmap

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` of name string like this :

```
HashMap<Integer, String> name = new HashMap<>();
```

Where `name[0] = Ram, Shyam, Mahesh`

I want to change `name[0] to "Ram", "Shyam", "Mahesh"`

Is there any inbuilt function to do it?

Comment: Urm I think you're confused. They are strings in your given example `name[0] = Ram, Shyam, Mahesh`.

Do you have a requirement for actually putting double quotes into the strings themselves? If so you'll need to look into escaping characters.

Comment: Do you want to change a single String value to a List of Strings? Or modify the String to contain quotes?

Comment: @ThomasCook Yes I need to put doubles quotes in that string values.

Comment: @f1sh Modify the string containing quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you use `replaceAll` like this :

```
String str = "Ram, Shyam, Mahesh";
str = str.replaceAll("\\w+", "\"$0\"");
//note \w can match [a-zA-Z0-9_] if you want only letters you can use [a-zA-Z]+
```

---

Note: this is just an example, in your case you have to change the value of hashmap instead

result is :

```
"Ram", "Shyam", "Mahesh"
```

---

**EDIT**

> Its working but if the string is separated by space character then it
>   is treating that string as two different strings i.e for string 'My
>   name' it is converting it into "My" "Name".

In this case you can use this regex instead :

```
str = str.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z\\s]+)(,\\s*)?", "\"$1\"$2");
```

Comment: Its working but if the string is seperated by space character then it is treating that string as two different strings i.e for string 'My name' it is converting it into "My" "Name".

Comment: check my edit @user7348570 hope this can help you

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code to do so...

```
        HashMap<Integer,String> name = new HashMap<>();
        name.put(10, " \"Ram\", \"Shyam\", \"Mahesh\"");
        String str = (String)name.get(10);
        System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.